# Web service call from .ajax, maxJsonLength error

Tags: json, jquery, asmx, javascriptserializer, jquery-pagination

I'm using .asmx web service and web service method can serialize to json string(3506 record) by using JavaScriptSerializer class and i don't get any error from VisualStudio.

On the other hand my phonegap app using this service and i can consume with that. But my last method contents 3506 records and when i call this method from javascript i get

> "error during serialization or deserialization using the json
>   javascriptserializer"

error.

Should i use paging or smth on web service? If yes can anybody tell me how to do that? Like i said i can use this method from browser. i can get this error when i call on javascript.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "WEB_SERVICE_URL",
        data: "{ dummyParameter:dummy }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            app.showLoading();         
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            clCard = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            alert(clCard.length);
        },
        complete: function() {
            app.hideLoading();
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            app.hideLoading();
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1151987/1276002). I think helped you.